# how can I convert the response of a rest call to an external api to a java dto in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am using webclient in order to make an api call to an external api from my spring boot application.
I am able to get a response but when I convert it to a dto all the values are null.
This is the dto:

```
public class AddressResponse {
private String street;
private String line1;
private String line2;
private String postcode;
private String country;
}
```

this is the method in the service that makes the call:

```
    public AddressResponse resolveAddress(AddressRequest addressRequest) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .queryParam("text", addressRequest.getSearchTerm())
            .queryParam("apiKey", apiKey)
            .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(AddressResponse.class)
            .block();
}
```

this is the response when I use postman and manually make a get call to the external api:

```
"results": [
    {
        "datasource": {
            "sourcename": "openstreetmap",
            "attribution": "© OpenStreetMap contributors",
            "license": "Open Database License",
            "url": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"
        },
        "name": "Bermondsey",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "country_code": "gb",
        "state": "England",
        "county": "Greater London",
        "city": "London"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can extract the fields from the json response with the `jackson` library converting the json to a `JsonNode` object and then manually extract the fields you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The response isn't mapped correctly because the fields in `AddressResponse` are actually nested in another JSON object.

You can create an additional class that would contain a list of `"results"`.

```java
public class AddressRootResponse {
    private List<AddressResponse> results;
        
    public List<AddressResponse> getResults {
        return this.results;
    }
        
    public void setResults(List<AddressResponse> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

And of course when you're making your call to the API, you need to change the given class from `AddressResponse.class` to `AddressRootResponse.class`.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the code but I think you can learn about Json structure. and use online tool "Json to POJO" to know more